# Run metadata not appearing in TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have the following code snippet which should add the run metadata to a TensorBoard file writer:

```
 run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
 # Check Metadata
 ecnn_run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
 # Run optimization and calculate batch loss
 _, ecnn_loss, ecnn_summary = ecnn_sess.run([ecnn_train_op, ecnn_loss_op, ecnn_merged], run_metadata=ecnn_run_metadata, options=run_options)
 ecnn_train_writer.add_run_metadata(ecnn_run_metadata, 'step%d' % ecnn_step)
 ecnn_train_writer.add_summary(ecnn_summary, ecnn_step)
 print("ECNN - Step " + str(ecnn_step) + " Loss " + str(ecnn_loss))
```

However, after launching TensorBoard, the metadata radio buttons in the graph view are still greyed out, and the tooltip tells me to add Run Metadata to the FileWriter. So it made no difference if i define the `tf.RunMetadata` object, pass it to `ecnn_sess.run` and then to the `ecnn_train_writer`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: That looks right to me ... is the graph passed to `ecnn_train_writer ` when it is constructed? ie, `ecnn_train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/logdir', sess.graph)`?

Comment: Yes, it is. The graph itself shows up in tensorboard, as well as all the scalars and images i defined. However, only the run metadata isn't visible. I think i can live without, but it still bugs me a little.

Comment: I know this is late but I though it might still be helpful since I faced a similar issue. I noticed that by default tensorboard selects no session run, so in the left menu you would have to select a run that (based on your code) will be named something like "step1", "step2", and so on..in the Session runs dropdown menu.